# Introduction to algorithms 22.1-7 the contradiction in answer?

Tags: algorithm

I am self-studying **Introduction to algorithms**, and am confused by the answer to 22.1-7.

Consider a directed graph with no self loop. I think it can be like picture3,
so the incidence matrix B should be
picture4
and the BT should be picture5
so The product of BBT should be picture6
i can understand the value in the  diagonal means the the number of edge connect with the point
but in BBT[1][4] the value is 1 (0*1+(-1)*(-1)+(-1)*0)
i confused and don’t understand what wrong with it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, I think it's excellent that you actually tried to verify it with an example.

Unfortunately, you don't specify your edge numbers, so it's unclear what your incidence matrix refers to.

Suppose we use the following numbering:

[image]

Then the incidence matrix is

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[-1, -1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, -1]])
>>> b
array([[-1, -1,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  1, -1]]
```

And the product is

```
>>> np.dot(b, b.T)
array([[ 2, -1, -1],
       [-1,  2, -1],
       [-1, -1,  2]])
```

which does not seem to be what you got, but actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: why not b = np.array([[0, -1, -1], [1, 0, 1], [1, -1, 0]])?

Comment: b[0][0]means point 1 connect to point 1 so  b[0][0]=0 (no self-loop) and b[0][1] edge from point 1 to point 2 so it should be -1 etc did i confuse something in incidence matrix?

Comment: "b[0][0]means point 1 connect to point 1" It does *not* mean that. The matrix `b` is a vertex to *edge* matrix, not a vertex to *vertex* matrix. The *i, j* entry discusses the relationship between vertex *i* and *edge j*.

Comment: o!!! incidence matrix i confuse the concept with adjacency matrix thank you very much now i get it